# How can I filter with inSetBind for multiple columns in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following table definition (simplified):

```
class Houses(tag: Tag) extends Table[HouseRow](tag, "HOUSE") {
  def houseId = column[Long]("HOUSE_ID", O.NotNull, O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def houseName = column[String]("HOUSE_NAME", O.NotNull)
  def houseType = column[String]("HOUSE_TYPE", O.NotNull)

  def uniqueHouseName = index("UQ_HOUSE_NAME_HOUSE_TYPE", (houseName, houseType), true)

  def * = (houseId, houseName, houseType) <> (HouseRow.tupled, HouseRow.unapply)
}

val houses = TableQuery[Houses]
```

I'd like to select houses that match on a set of the uniqueHouseName index as follows.

```
case class HouseKey(houseName: String, houseType: String)
val houseKeys: Seq(HouseKey("name1", "type1"), HouseKey("name2", "type2"))
```

A naive `inSetBind` filter will match on for eg. `HouseRow(ID, "name1", "type2")` which is incorrect.
In MySql I would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM HOUSE h
WHERE(h.HOUSE_TYPE, d.HOUSE_NAME) IN
(
  SELECT 'type1' as HOUSE_TYPE, 'name1' as HOUSE_NAME
  UNION
  SELECT 'type2', 'name2'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting tuxdna's answer to allow arbitrary seqs. This query can however not be precompiled to SQL at the moment and has a runtime overhead.

```
val filteredHouses =  
  houses.filter(h =>
    houseKeys.map(hk => h.houseName === hk.houseName && h.houseType === hk.houseType)
              .reduce(_ || _)
  )
```

Comment: Just a warning, `reduce` blows up on an empty list.

Answer (score 5):

Like @cvogt version, but doesn't blow up on empty list:

```
val filteredHouses = 
  houses.filter(h =>
    houseKeys.map(hk => h.houseName === hk.houseName &&
        h.houseType === hk.houseType)
      .reduceOption(_ || _).getOrElse(false: Rep[Boolean])
)
```

Tested in slick 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete answer, but for only two pairs of values you could do this:

```
   val filteredHouses =  for {
      h <- houses
      if (h.houseName === "name1" && h.houseType === "type1") || (
        h.houseName === "name2" && h.houseType === "type2")
    } yield h
```